# ASP.NET - Practical difference between HttpContext.Current.Application and static Dictionary?

Tags: asp.net

At the moment I'm implementing some piece of code that makes use of the `HttpContext.Current.Application` as some kind of caching system. To me it looks like it could easily be replaced by a static Dictionary though, removing the dependency on the `HttpContext`.

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179949/647845) that is quite similar, but in the answer there is no explanation why anyone would ***ever*** go for the `HttpApplicationState` approach at all.

In summary: what particular problem does the `HttpApplicationState` solve that is not already solvable in a myriad of other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a dependency on HttpContext anyway

You can define a interface contract for Cache mechanism

And then implement that by HttpContext, AppFabric and so on

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question :) added a summary to make the specific question more clear.

Comment: @DirkBoer Yes (-: , I've edited my answer before, because I've had understood you question badly, But I didn't delete useful parts

Answer (score 0):

Static will be shared across all http applications hosted within the same application pool, `HttpContext.Current.Application` would be scoped to the current app.  They would only be equivalent if the app pool is hosting only one application.