# Access Application global variable from WCF that runs asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, global-asax

I am trying to access global.asax application variable from WCF, that's my goal at least. I've tried many type of solutions, but the one that I am trying now is using static variables.

I've created a StaticVariable.cs class like so:

```
  public static class StaticVariables
    {
        private static string _Key = "name1";

        public static Object someInfo
        {
            get
            {    
                return HttpContext.Current.Application[_Key];
            }           
        } 
    }
```

The Application["name1"] is initialized in the global.asax.cs. I can read it when I access my webservice but not in my WCF service.

In my WCF I call the StaticVariables `someInfo` to retrieve the data, but I get:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null error
```

My WCF is running asynchronously and its called from within a webservice using `Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync`. So I assume that the problem is that the WCF runs not on the main thread, but I am not sure.

So it seems that the Static class doesn't work in my case and I wanted to know how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use static variables ?

`HttpContext` is dependent on ASP.NET pipeline. In a host-agnostic model (OWIN or self-hosted) you don't have access to it.

Application storage in `HttpApplicationState` is only useful if you need to access the current HttpContext. If it's not necessary, you should simply use static properties.

Moreover, `HttpApplicationState` was initially created for backward compatibility with classic ASP.

```
public static class StaticVariables
{
    public static object SomeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

See also [Singleton and HttpApplicationState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179923/singleton-and-httpapplicationstate) and http://forums.asp.net/t/1574797.aspx